# How do I install downloaded .deb file

Tags: package-management, software-installation, updates

I have Password Safe installed and running OK on my 20.04 LTS notebook.

I got an email advising of an updated version so I downloaded
passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb

I found and followed advice from this site to install the update as follows:

```
chris@CandKAcer:~$ sudo dpkg -i passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb
[sudo] password for chris: 
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb': No such file or directory
chris@CandKAcer:~$
```

The file `passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb` is in my downloads folder.

What did I do wrong?

I also tried to Install it by extracting it in Archive Manager, but no go. In an earlier version of Ubuntu the Archive Manager had an Install button which worked fine, but the Extract button in Archive Manager 3.36.1 doesn't do the same!

I know this should be easy, but I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm struggling with this.

Precise step by step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running the command: `find $HOME -name passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb` which will give you the location of your file...

Answer (score 4):

#### GUI Method 1

1. Install "GDebi Package Installer" from Ubuntu software store.
2. Right-click on the `.deb` file.
3. Select "Open with other application".
4. Open the file with "GDebi Package Installer".
5. Authenticate.
6. Press install.

#### GUI Method 2

1. Right-click on the `.deb` file.
2. Select "Open with other application".
3. Open the file with "Software Install".
4. Authenticate.
5. Press "Install".

#### Command Line Method 1

1. Open terminal.
2. Type `sudo dpkg -i /home/chris/Downloads/passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Command Line Method 2

1. Open terminal.
2. Type `cd Downloads` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type `sudo dpkg -i passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: So I should have switched to the Downloads folder before trying to instal. Now I know.  Thanks.
But...
chris@CandKAcer:~$ cd Downloads
chris@CandKAcer:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb
[sudo] password for chris: 
dpkg: regarding passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb containing passwordsafe:
 passwordsafe conflicts with passwordsafe-common
  passwordsafe-common (version 1.08.2+dfsg-1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing passwordsafe
Errors were en

Comment: That is pretty unclear but it seems that it won't allow you to update it. Try uninstalling the one you have and installing the new one.

Comment: Try the GUI method and tell me what happens. Also, I personally use "GDebi Package Installer" when I install using GUI. You can get it from Ubuntu Software store.

Comment: I unistalled password-common as this was a conflict, but now ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of passwordsafe:
 passwordsafe depends on libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.0-2) | libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0-2); however:
  Package libwxgtk3.0-0v5 is not installed.
  Package libwxgtk3.0-0 is not installed.
 passwordsafe depends on libqrencode3 (>= 3.4.4-1); however:
  Package libqrencode3 is not installed.

Comment: So I tried to find and install the missing packages libwxgtk3.0-0v5, libwxgtk3.0-0, libqrencode3 

But I could not find these 

chris@CandKAcer:~$ sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-0v5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libwxgtk3.0-0v5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
The same is true for the other 2

Comment: Did you try the GDebi? It usually fixes dependency issues. Also, this problem could occur because that package is not configured to support Ubuntu 20.04 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Other than dpkg command, you can install gdebi:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

gdebi uses in a transparent way dpkg for installing deb packages but also *managing automatically the dependencies*: so if you don't want to personally worry about dependencies, use gdebi.

```
sudo gdebi <package-name.deb>
```

Comment: I installed gdebi and tried to install passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb and got
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>=3.0.0-2)|- libwxgtk3.0-0(>=3.0.0-2)
I also stumbled across passwordsafe-ubuntu16-1.06.0-BETA.amd64.deb, which is the earlier version of Password Safe that I had somehow installed, but that no longer works, so I tried to reinstall that via gdebi and got the same error

Comment: It seems that now your problem is not "how to install a deb package" but "how to solve the dependency errrors". I've found this link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=passwordsafe If I'm not wrong about the package, there is a version available for focal fossa at the link: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/passwordsafe (click in the table at the end of the page the link for your architecture). Consider also that the package is available also through a simple sudo apt install passwordsafe in your terminal.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz.
I did not know about the dependency issue until I knew how to install a DEB package, like everything else easy when you know how.
A new DEB package for Ubuntu 20.04 has been developed and is now available, so problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Downloads directory before executing the command:

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd Downloads`
3. `sudo dpkg -i passwordsafe-ubuntu18-1.10-amd64.deb`

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy way. Thanks.

Comment: After trying this there are other issues with dependencies that prevented the install, but I am making progress. Thanks again.